# Question on Chrome's Certificate Revocation Checking

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, actions-on-google, certificate-revocation

I would like to understand how Chrome checks for certificate revocation status when validating SSL certificates. Could someone please explain what method Chrome uses to verify whether a certificate has been revoked? Proper revocation checking is an important security practice, so I would appreciate any details you can provide on how this works in Chrome.

Thank you in advance for your assistance. Please let me know if you need any clarification from me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Related reference https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/crlsets/